# Can I create a symbolic link/junction to a Teams folder without issue? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Tags: network-shares, symbolic-link, shared-folders, microsoft-teams, user-folders

I'm new to using Teams, and am not a networking professional etc. so please forgive my ignorance there, and if I'm using incorrect terms for things, but here is my situation:

I have to use some old software that is out of support (there is no chance of getting them to update it to e.g. integrate with Teams), on which I create files that have links to other files (which also want to be synced between users), using an absolute path, which must be (or appear to be) a local path. I'd like these files to be synced between a few computers in different physical locations (not on a LAN), so that we're all using the same version, but there's an issue I'm running into:

To put it simply, the software creates e.g. `MasterFile.dat` which also then, when used/accessed, references/pulls data from `SubFile.dat`. Both Master and Sub files need to be synced within the Teams share to ensure version consistency across users.

The absolute paths generated and used, when trying to use the Teams synced/shared folder, point to e.g. `C:\Users\[local PC Windows username]\[Teams account name]\Folder\Subfile.dat`.

Of course the `[Teams account name]` is the same across all of the PCs because we're all logged into the same Teams share, but the local PC username differs, and so when User 1 (let's call them John) creates and saves a synced master file, it points to `C:\Users\John\[Teams account name]\Folder\Subfile.dat` and when User 2 (Bill) tries to load the synced master file on his local PC, that path does not exist, since his Teams share file is in `C:\Users\Bill\...`

Now I've thought of a few potential ways to get around this:

- If I could move the Teams sync folder location outside of the Users folder, I think that would work... but I can't see a way to change this location anywhere (perhaps there is a way I'm missing - I have googled for a solution and also searched here didn't find anything relevant). Note also I can't use windows environment variables like `%USERPROFILE%` in the filenames as the software I'm using won't accept it and there's no way to change that.
- I could make it so that each user has to have a Windows user account on their local machine named the same thing, e.g. it could be named `TeamsShare` or something, through which they access Teams and also the software needed. That way, for every user, the files will be referenced locally in `C:\Users\TeamsShare\...` This may be a bit of a pain to setup as I believe I'd have to reinstall several pieces of software on the machines in question(?).
- A seemingly simpler way is using a symbolic link/folder junction using `mklink` in a command prompt, as detailed here: https://www.howtogeek.com/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Now, currently I have actually set up a Junction using `mklink /J`, such that I now have a (virtual) folder `C:\Teams\` which is a junction to `C:\Users\[local PC Windows username]\[Teams account name]`, and it does appear to work correctly. I would of course then have to set up the same folder junction on each of the users' computers, to their respective users folders - which would be easy as it's only a couple of computers currently.

Basically I'm just wondering if there are any potential issues with what I've done (like, will the symbolic link break and need to be setup again if Teams is not running?), or if there is some easier/more reliable method for achieving this that I'm missing.

I will reiterate that this software has to work this way, I cannot alter the way it works, and I have to use it - there is no alternative, and no support available.

Also if it's not really possible to set this up in a robust way using Teams, I would be potentially open to using some other file syncing solution - but ideally it has to work as seamlessly and be as straightforward to set up etc. as Teams is.

Comment: In terms of ease-of-use, your probably have a decent solution using symlinks if the software won't take `%userprofile%` for folder paths. Another option is to mount that folder to a drive letter like with `subst T: %userprofile%\OrgName\TeamsFolder`. Then just use `T:\Subfile.bat` as the path (so you don't need to make a new folder for symlinks)

Comment: Just be aware of synchronization issues. What do you expect/want to happen if two people make changes at the same time? Teams can take a while to sync local files around. Depending on the app, that might be totally fine, or you may want to move to something like sharepoint with checkin/checkout

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Like i said I'm new to Teams but it seems that Sharepoint is integral to Teams file management anyway - the only way you can access file version history is through Sharepoint. I had a bit of a play around with it the other day and you can indeed to check-in/out this way.